# Prestashop 1.7 admin theme css overrides

Tags: themes, admin, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to modify the PS 1.7 admin theme - simply to hide a few options and menu items.

I modified ./adminFolder/themes/default/css/override.css

And it works everywhere, except at Catalog/Products and Modules - as if there were no overrides.

How can I get the css overrides to work globally in the admin area?

Comment: Hello, @fluka. You have two answers, make sure to provide some feedback. Having free advices from passionate développer is great; but it cannot be taken for granted. Make sure to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide menu/sub-menus, you can set the visibility from within the database in the table `[PREFIX]_tab` (default is `ps_tab`).

The top menu has 0 for `id_parent` and submenus has a value superior to 0.

[image: Table PS_tab in PHPMyAdmin]

By example, I have this vehicle file custom module:

[image: Menu including a custom module]

If I set the row with the `class_name` "*V2vVehicleFile*" to `active = 0` (false), then the whole menu (including its submenus) disappear.

[image: Vehicle file menu has disappeared]

Now, if I set the row with the `class_name` "*AdminVehicleMake*" to `active = 0` (false), then only the submenus named "*Vehicle make*" disappear.

[image: Only the vehicle make sub menu has disappeared]

Comment: Note: I just updated to version 1.7.0.6. and it overrides the modifications I made in `override.css` before updating. This proves that the file is no longer reliable in versions 1.7.X. The update also crashed my test project, so you better wait a little bit before doing the 1-click update.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. This answer is the only place I have found that actually shows how to turn off menu items in the sidebar when prestashop leaves uninstalled tabs in the admin menu. The one click upgrade menu item remained even after completely uninstalling the module, but this worked perfectly to remove it from the admin menu in 1.7.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

The product controller is already in the new system (symfony).

Looking at the source code you can see that it uses 5 css:

```
/modules/welcome/public/module.css
/admin/themes/new-theme/public/theme.css
/js/jquery/plugins/chosen/jquery.chosen.css
/admin/themes/default/css/vendor/nv.d3.css
/admin/themes/default/css/bundle/right-sidebar.css
```

The overrides.css is only for the "old theme". And I don't know of any for the new one.
So either you change one of these, and run the risk of being overwritten on upgrade. Or override the `AdminController->setMedia($isNewTheme = false)` to add your custom css. Or use the `Hook::exec('actionAdminControllerSetMedia');` in a module to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the overrides.css file location to the function named setMedia in classes/controller/AdminController.php

```
public function setMedia($isNewTheme = false)
{
    if ($isNewTheme) {
        $this->addCSS(__PS_BASE_URI__ . $this->admin_webpath . '/themes/default/css/overrides.css', 'all', 1);
```