# prestashop 1.7 add new link to backoffice side menu

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I should add a static link to an external resource in the backoffice side menu, but I can't figured out how.

All I see when I google something like that is "create a module...", but I just need a link, static one, non-translatable, just this

`<a href="http://example.com/catdin/generate">GO TO DYNAMIC CATALOG GENERATOR</a>`

That's it.

Can that be done? I f possible, I would append that link to the Catalog section of the nav side menu of the backoffice.

Any hint? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your link in *admin-dev/themes/default/template/nav.tpl*  after "ul.menu"

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="http://example.com/catdin/generate">GO TO DYNAMIC CATALOG GENERATOR</a></li>
```

Of course you should override nav.tpl to not change the original one.

Look at this thread [Prestashop 1.7 admin theme css overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665797/prestashop-1-7-admin-theme-css-overrides) it can help you.

Comment: thank you very much @Melvita. I ended up by putting a button in the header, but I am going to follow your suggestiong as well.